# Fast Calculation of Fiedler Eigenvector for Large Matrices in Python

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, svd, eigenvector

I have been calculating the Fiedler eigenvector for matrices up to 10K x 10K in size using numpy/scipy eigendecomposition operators in Python.  But I want to scale to larger matrices (e.g., 100K and more), and perform the calculation as fast as possible. For 10K, it takes me a few minutes to do the eigendecomposition.  Here is the code I am currently using:

```
from scipy.linalg import eigh
w,v = eigh(lapMat)
sortWInds = argsort(w)
fVec = v[:,sortWInds[1]]
```

From the little I understand about Spark, the eigendecomposition operator still requires a lot of cross talk between cores in a distributed system. I ran some tests thru a contractor and didn't see the speed-up I was hoping for using Spark on a multi-core AWS AMI.  Here is the main code used to perform SVDs on an AWS Linux Ubuntu AMI:

```
#Benchmarking Setup - Configure here for the benchmark size required
sizes=[10000]
cores=[64]

max_cores_for_a_single_executor=8

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.mllib.random import RandomRDDs
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors

# Iterate over matrix of size in sizes
for size in sizes:
    # Iterate over number of cores used
    for core in cores:
        # Calculating spark configuration for a distributed setup
        executor_cores= max_cores_for_a_single_executor if core>max_cores_for_a_single_executor else core

        executors=1 if core/max_cores_for_a_single_executor==0 else core/max_cores_for_a_single_executor

        #Initializing Spark
        conf = SparkConf().setAppName("SVDBenchmarking")\
        .set("spark.executor.cores",executor_cores)\
        .set("spark.executor.instances",executors) \
        .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled","false")\
        .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize","25g")\
        .set("spark.executor.memory", "60g")\
        sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
        start = datetime.now()

        # Input matrix of specific size generated and saved earlier
        inputRdd=sc.textFile("hdfs://ip-172-31-34-253.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/data/input"+str(size))

        inputRdd=sc.textFile("/Users/data/input"+str(size))
        intermid2=inputRdd\
            .map(lambda x: textToVector(x))\
            .sortByKey()\
            .map(lambda x: extract(x))

        mat=RowMatrix(intermid2)

        # Step-2
        # running SVD
        svd = mat.computeSVD(size, computeU=True)
        U = svd.U  # The U factor is a RowMatrix.
        s = svd.s  # The singular values are stored in a local dense vector.
        V = svd.V  # The V factor is a local dense matrix.

        # Stoping clock for benchmark
        end = datetime.now()
```

Given the eigenstructure of a matrix is key for recommendation algorithms there must be "community" efforts available for calculating SVDs far faster than a single-core approach in numpy/scipy.

There have also been recent efforts at multigrid algorithms for explicitly calculating the Fielder eigenvector [Urschel 2014](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.0565).  I think at one time he made Matlab code available.

Does anyone have any pointers to 1) understanding the state-of-the-art for rapidly calculating non-dominant eigenvectors/SVs (such as the Fiedler eigenvector) in large matrices, 2) public codebases for performing these operations, preferably in Python, or at least callable from Python, and 3) recommendations for architectures to perform calculations for matrices of this size or bigger (> 10K) that don't swamp the RAM?

Thanks (and humbly),

Nirmal

Comment: Can you show us the code you're used so far, as well as what you're tried to scale up to larger matrices? This is important in creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Moreover, questions asking for recommendations will be flagged as opinion-based.

Comment: Sure, will do shortly.